# JAVA - Executor Schedule get Time until next run

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice, executor

Currently using a `ScheduledExecutorService` to do a task every 45 minutes (for infinity).

```
 executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               ...
 }, 10, 45 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I was wondering if there was a proper way to know how long until the next iteration of the executor?

My un-proper way is to add a timer and resetting it every iterator of the executor but it feels very bad.